# What is the behavior of the Artillery Beam targeting?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

The [Federation Cruiser's](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Ships#Federation_Cruiser) [Artillery Beam](http://ftl.wikia.com/wiki/Artillery_Beam) fires automatically without allowing you any targeting preferences. I've had it cut through most rooms of the enemy ship, or just a few. Is there any means or method to how it chooses to lay the line of it's beam or is it random? Is there a minimum\maximum number of rooms it can hit?

Comment: I would say that, like any other computer-based weapon (such as the drones), it's random. Do you have any reason to believe otherwise?

Comment: There is no direct reason to believe in Extra-terrestrials but many people do anyway, some questions are asked simply because the answer isn't jumping into anyones face.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [wiki](http://ftlwiki.com/wiki/The_Osprey):

> Since the beam fires automatically **and randomly**, it can strike multiple rooms or just one.
>   *[emphasis mine]*

This gives you an advantage against larger ships as the variance between two randomly selected points will be larger, which means the average difference will be higher, which of course means you have the potential to hit more rooms, and thus do more damage.